# What check can Ι perform to verify that a load cell is operating properly?

Tags: load-cell, damage, checklist

About five years ago I was tasked to develop the software for a small custom made testing machine (everything is custom-made from frame, to the measuring system). Last year, I was volunteered to  "inherit" the maintenance of the system (which is used a few times per year).

About a month ago, I had a complaint that the force measurement was not giving reasonable results. Upon closer inspection, I realized that there was an unpredictable behavior, ie. the force would increase and fall by  at least +/- 2.5%, over the course of a few tenths of seconds.

One thing I am worried is that, this testing machine has been used to test specimens over the capacity of the load cell 2tf ( which I hope I am correctly translating to 20kN ), and this unpredictable behavior is the result of this mistreatment.

My questions are :

- how would a damaged loadcell behave?
- how can I test the integrity of the load cell?

Below is the only image  I have on the load cell. Also the closest reference is in the following [link](https://tml.jp/e/product/transducers/compress.html)

[image]

### my thoughts on how to check.

One of my thoughts on how to proceed is that, I have another load cell (of smaller capacity ) that I could try out.  The reason, I am considering this, is that I am worried about is whether the power supplies and/or accompanying electronic/bridge amplifier circuits are starting to show their age and have become unstable (although I haven't spotted any bulged capacitors).

Ideally, I would like to cross out that the rest of the circuit has a problem. The way I am planning to do that is by replacing the load cell, and checking that with the other loadcell, given a dead load, the standard deviation of the load cell signal acquired over a few seconds at 200Hz sampling rate is in the order of 0.5% of the full range of the load cell.

If I then compare the standard deviation with respect to the full range, I should be able to determine whether there is something unsightly.

Buying a new loadcell or replacing the amplifier circuit is not prohibitive, however  I am on a budget, so I want to make an informed decision. Also, I have access to power supplies and oscilloscopes and (I guess) most of the hobbyist's electrical workshop tools.

Comment: A damaged load cell could do anything...

Comment: Is it possible for you to contact the manufacturer and ask? They are the only one who can answer your question for this specific load cell.

Comment: @Cravero, that is definitely a way to go, although, I was hoping for something more hands on/practical, than exchnagning email.  I'll update my question with things I have available for testing.

Comment: Do you know the type of load cell? Is it a strain gauge or a MFR based load cell? What cables/connections does it have?

Comment: No, I don't but I could have a look.  Because I've never come across the term, by MFR you mean Magnetic Force Restoration ? Also, could you help me in what I should be looking for? I mean will it be different by something as evident as e.g. the number of cables

Comment: You can simulate the loadcell with some resistors and a potentiometer. Similarly, you can measure the resistance of the load cell. Most of the load cell failures I have observed have exhibited significant zero point shift. What you describe sounds like wiring or instrumentation problems.

Comment: Agree with Kartman. If the load cell were overloaded, a moderate overload would result in permanent deformation, and shift the offset mostly, but I don't believe it would cause noise. A more serious overload could break something (depending on the design of the case) and all bets are off.

Comment: PS - the link in the question indicates it is a strain gauge type... more possible links [here, CLG type](https://tml.jp/eng/documents/transducers/CLG-NB.pdf), and [here, wiring](https://tml.jp/eng/documents/transducers/loadcells_description.pdf) ... the wiring link shows it is an uncompensated load cell, convenient for troubleshooting